# Rails image manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing

in our website we are retrieving data from an API, which does not pull images bigger than 100 × 75 pixels, then we show them listed. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCn0D.png) We need to double up this size to match with our design.

Is there any Gem that does this, without loosing quality and not impacting performance?

Comment: Yes, there are such tools. Unfortunately, these are reserved to be used by movie production companies. ^^

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to upscale an image without losing quality - you're basically asking an algorithm to fill in image data that simply does not exist in the file in the first place.

However, depending on the rate of the scaling and the images themselves, you could have acceptable results.

Since you want to do this effectively and there is no benefit of doing the resizing on the server anyway, I'd advise simply using CSS to achieve this on the client side - just set the desired width/height attributes for the specific `img` elements.

If you really want to do this on the server (e.g. if you need to save the resulting images), one option would be to use the Paperclip gem's [image processing capabilities](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor).